Why JPA @Version occasionally not working?
@Service
@Slf4j
public class InvoiceQueue implements TaskQueue<InvoiceSummary> {
    ......
    @Autowired
    private InvoiceRenderService renderService;

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public InvoiceSummary hold(long timeout) {
        InvoiceSummary invoiceSummary = renderService.fetchOne();
        if (invoiceSummary == null) {
            ThreadUtils.sleep(Duration.of(timeout, ChronoUnit.MILLIS));
        } else {
            log.info("render start,InvoiceId:[{}],InvoiceName:[{}]", invoiceSummary.getInvoiceId(),
                    invoiceSummary.getInvoiceName());
        }
        return invoiceSummary;
    }
    ......
}

 public InvoiceSummary fetchOne() {
    try {
        InvoiceSummary invoiceSummary = invoiceSummaryService.findFirstByRenderInfo_Status(ReadyRender);
        if (invoiceSummary == null) {
            return null;
        }
        invoiceSummary.getRenderInfo().setStatus(Rendering);
        return invoiceSummaryService.save(invoiceSummary);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //捕获异常，返回null，防止异常发生时不hold，无限循环
        log.error("fetch error", e);
        return null;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(name = "invoiceId",columnNames = {"invoiceId"})})
@Getter
@Setter
public class InvoiceSummary extends BaseAudit implements Task {
    ...
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String invoiceId;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "renderInfoId",unique = true)
    private InvoiceRenderInfo renderInfo;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class InvoiceRenderInfo {
    ...
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RenderStatus status;

    @Version
    private Integer version;
    ...
}


some logs:
[][INFO][2024-08-05 08:52:22.799][invoice-render-5][InvoiceQueue.java][29] render start,InvoiceId:[4535],InvoiceName:[Best Western Invoice - Jul 2024]
[][INFO][2024-08-05 08:52:22.805][invoice-render-2][InvoiceQueue.java][29] render start,InvoiceId:[4535],InvoiceName:[Best Western Invoice - Jul 2024]
[][INFO][2024-08-05 08:52:22.805][invoice-render-4][InvoiceQueue.java][29] render start,InvoiceId:[4535],InvoiceName:[Best Western Invoice - Jul 2024]



Three threads simultaneously execute the fetchOne method(They are accessing the same data), all successfully saving.
In my understanding, InvoiceRenderInfo contains a Version field. If one thread succeeds, the other two should throw an ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException when saving. However, in reality, it occasionally happens (very rarely) that all three threads succeed simultaneously.
@Version is effective elsewhere, but it's only in this specific scenario that the unexpected behavior occurs.
I was unable to reproduce this situation on my local machine; when I ran multiple threads simultaneously executing this piece of code locally, only one thread succeeded

I have identified the issue. Because findFirstByRenderInfo_Status generates two SQL queries, the first one retrieves invoiceSummary, and the second one retrieves invoiceRenderInfo. If another thread updates the status of invoiceRenderInfo between these two queries, the current thread may not detect the status change and might skip the update statement. Therefore, the solution is to add @Transactional to the fetchOne method, ensuring that both queries operate within the same transaction.
